# Can't find plist in PhoneGap project

Tags: iphone, audio, cordova, plist

I am developing an Audio Application for iOS using PhoneGap and the audio stops when iPhone's screen is locked. I have read that you need to define in ".plist" file what processes should be run in background. However I am unable to find any plist file on my windows machine.

I am building PhoneGap for iOS remotely using latest version.

Answer (score 0):

go to Resource folder on your phoneGap project .`Resource ->your apps name-info.Plist` file will be there.

Comment: There is no Resource folder. There is one "res" under www but that has default icons only

Comment: without Xcode how are you doing iOS apps in phonegap

Comment: are youable to add iOS platform and  able to build your apps in iOS platform means

Comment: No it won't allow me to iOS platform locally. But I am able to use this command to compile online "phonegap remote build ios"

Comment: is possible to update your plist file by remote.  path like this Resource ->your apps name-info.Plist.ios build project only have plist file

Comment: This is what I get when i try to add iOS
C:\Users\me.domain\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\in
stall.js:72
    self.phonegap.emit('log', 'detecting', platform.human, 'SDK environment...
                                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'human' of undefined
    at InstallCommand.execute (C:\Users\me.domain\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\phonegap\lib\phonegap\install.js:72:52)
    at InstallCommand.run (C:\Users\me.domain\AppData\Roaming\np.......
......... and so on

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47749/discussion-between-sport-and-anjum)

Comment: An example please. I am TOTALLY new to PhoneGap and thsi plist business :-(

Answer (score 0):

on the `config.xml` file of phonegap project you can add:

```
<config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
    <feature name="AllowBackgroundAudio">
        <param name="ios-package" value="AllowBackgroundAudio" onload="true" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
</config-file>
```

Or you can try using the [cordova-allow-background-audio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-allow-background-audio) plugin.